# Give focus to specific figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I have a script, which I need to interact with both via command line and UI interaction through some figures.

How do I programmatically switch the focus between console and full screen figure?

If I do `figure()` then a new figures is open in front of Matlab, but it does not have the focus. I have not idea how to do the opposite...

Comment: See [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88176-keep-focus-in-command-window#answer_97749), and the function [`commandwindow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/commandwindow.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a clean solution, but a workaround:

```
% Create figure
testFigure = figure();

pause(3);

% Hide
testFigure.Visible='off';

pause(3);

% Bring to front
testFigure.Visible='off';
testFigure.Visible='on';
```

Works for me on R2017b.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a figure, assign it to a handle

```
myFig1 = figure;
myFig2 = figure;
```

Then switch using

```
figure(myFig1); % Switches to myFig1
figure(myFig2); % Switches to myFig2
```

---

You can do the same with figure indices, but that is less clear and more prone to errors, for instance if you close/open other figures before switching

```
figure(1); % Initialise and/or switch to figure 1
```

---

Both of those methods will switch the active window to be the relevant figure window. To switch the active *figure* but keep the active *window* as the main Matlab editor, use `set`

```
set(0, 'CurrentFigure', myFig1)
```

Comment: You might want to include a mention of `gcf` and similar functions to get the figure handle for existing figures.

Comment: If the OP is looking to switch between figures, it's likely they're not interested in the current one? [For other readers, `gcf` gets the current figure]